# External Vendor Scripts( JS, Jquery) Not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am creating a web app frontend using ReactJS. I have downloaded a Template from some theme website  designed using HTML5 CSS3 Custom JS  and bootstrap and jquery and also includes some third party/vendor JS/Jquery Plugins Like nice-select, bootstrap, owl-carousel.

So when I click a button some modal or dropdown button does not open, but when i run the html file of folder they run absolutely fine. But in my react I am not able to make them work. Although all css files are working.

Like when i click profile icon this type of pop up open , `in plain theme file with assets and vendor files`.
[image: In plain theme file]

I copied the asset folder which is required in my `react public/` folder and still this pop up does not open. And when i directly write class to the element in inspect edit HTML pop up shows up. But not directly on click.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <title>React App</title>



  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/flatpickr.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Appear JavaScript -->
  <script src="./assets/js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
  <!-- Countdown JavaScript -->
 
  <script src="./assets/js/custom.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="./assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

i have tried importing jquery direct and run it , using the CDN of bootstrap with popper and whole bundle.  Nothing working. I can see whole css but pops and charts are not showing up.